# Failed to load resource - Ionic 7.0.1 / Angular 15.2.6 - Hosted on Netlify

Tags: angular, api, rest, ionic-framework, safari

I'm currently working on a survey-like project. You can click through multiple pages and fill in information. Everytime the "next" button is clicked, the data of the current page is sent to my RestAPI (hosted on DigitalOcean) and saved to a mysql database.

Everything works fine on localhost. On Netlify however some of my api calls just fail with the console error *[Error] Failed to load resource: Die Netzwerkverbindung wurde unterbrochen.* which is German for "The network connection was lost."

The Data for that specific page will not be saved.

I've only encountered this phenomenon in Safari Browser.

Does someone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help!